# Passing variables between methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, global-variables

I wish that the variables annoInizio and annoFine are usable within the mostrarisultato method. How can I do? I tried different solutions but I could not. I think I serve the global variables used anywhere within the code.

```
    - (id)init {
    if (self == [super init]) {
        NSDate *adesso = [NSDate date];
        NSDateComponents *adessoComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:adesso];
        //NSDate *dopo = [NSDate date];
        NSDateComponents *dopoComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:adesso];


        NSDate *oggiAMezzanotte = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:adessoComponents];
        NSDate *oggifinito = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dopoComponents];
        //[datePicker setDateValue:oggiAMezzanotte];
        //[datePicker2 setDateValue:oggiAMezzanotte];

        int daysToAdd = 364;
        NSDate *newDate1 = [oggifinito dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
        self.dataInizio = oggiAMezzanotte;
        int annoInizio = [adessoComponents year];
        NSLog(@"Anno inizio %i.", annoInizio);
        self.dataFine = newDate1;// Sets these to "now"
        NSDateComponents *newDate1Components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:newDate1];
        int annoFine = [newDate1Components year];
        NSLog(@"Anno fine %i.", annoFine);
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)mostrarisultato:(id)sender;
{



    if (dataFine<dataInizio) {
        [NSApp beginSheet:theSheet
           modalForWindow:(NSWindow *)_window
            modalDelegate:self
           didEndSelector:nil
              contextInfo:nil];
    } else {
        [progressIndicator startAnimation: self];
        [textView setString: @""];
        int lunedi = 0;
        int martedi = 0;
        int mercoledi = 0;
        int giovedi = 0;
        int venerdi = 0;
        int sabato = 0;
        int domenica = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One object-oriented way to handle that would be a class method which caches the result:

```
+ (int) annoInizio {
    static int singleton;
    if (!singleton) {
        ....
        singleton = ....;
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

The other way is an instance variable. For example dataInizio, appears to be both an instance variable and a property.

And of course you could use a global variable instead. Just add 'int annoInizio' to the top of the file and change `int annoInizio = ...` to `annoInizio = ...` in `-init`.